# eloquent migration does not follow the name order

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i go some **foreign keys problems**

so i **deleted** all the tables in DB and **changed the migrations names** so i get this **arrangement**:

[image]

but i always got thie error in table 10... because it does not follow the name order

```
(errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The migrations does not follow the names order but the timestamp on the file. So change the time on the file the first part `7_04_..` to whichever comes next of the one you are trying to add a foreign key to. The field and table have to exist in order for the foreign key constraint to work.

When Laravel generates a migration the first part is the current timestamp, and then it follows the name of your migration, so please use that, there is no need to manually edit the file names of the migrations.

Comment: before the 1_.. , 2_... it was 2019_...  in all files so i rename the 2019 part from 1 to 21

Comment: Yes, and that's what it should be. Don't change those names please. That's a Laravel convention does not make sense to make a custom order like that.

Comment: oh by the name i meant the timestamps parts and i got this errors

Comment: You should not do that.. If you want to take advantage of the generator. Your order does not make sense.

Comment: can you give an example for the first 2 migrations so i can understand please

Comment: so instead of `1_10_12_00000..` change just the last part to make the order, like this: `2019_10_12_000000..` this will be first, next you can add `2019_11_12_00000` this will be next day and so on. But don't change the first part. And make sure that the order of the tables is correct. So don't add a foreign key to a table that has not been created yet.